# Unknown CMake command "collect"

Tags: c, cmake

I need help in building a binary file with the help of cmake toolchain file

I have the below structure

- lib also included with header files
- examples/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/demo -- will contain the Demo by using those src nd header files.

I was able to build library(.a) file with the include and lib

But not knowing how would I able to build the binary for the demo

****toolchain file**********

add_subdirectory(examples)

error:
CMake Error at examples/CMakeLists.txt:1 (collect):
  Unknown CMake command "collect".

CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Comment: Please show us the `CMakeLists.txt` files relevant for the errors. If possible try to make a [mcve] of them. And is the error you show the *full* and *complete* and *copy-pasted* output?

Comment: `CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set` - please show us the makefile and full errors. Did you forget to `project(...)`? Did you forget to `cmake_minimum_required(..)` ?